# Regular Expression to find a match and append symbol to result

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write regular expression to find a number and append symbol to found match.

Input Text:

> Double Espresso   4.75 Subtotal   72.45 Tax   5.98

Regx to find Tax amount/value:

```
(?<=(TAX|Tax)(\t+|\s+))(.*)(\d*)?.?(\d*)?(\d+)
```

Above regx find tax amount 5.98 but I need to append $ or # so the final result becomes $5.98 OR #5.98.

The regular expression is fed to a third party application which takes whatever is returned from Regx so, I cannot write c# code to manipulate regx results separately therefore find and append needs to be done in single regular expression.

I could not find any way to append or replace regx match/result. Is there any way?

aforementinoed Regx can be tested [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester):

Comment: Sorry, if you *extract* some text with a regex you cannot add anything to it simultaneously. You either replace or append something after extracting using string operations.

Comment: You can maybe find the results of your current regex, append $ signs in your original string, then send a new regex and a new string which contains the signs to your third party application?

Comment: *find and append needs to be done in single regular expression* It is interesting - does third party know that it must replace matches? Because replacing is *another* action.

Answer (score 2):

this can be achieved by using negative lookahead

```
input
```

> Double Espresso 4 Mocha 55.42 Subtotal 72.45 Tax 5.98

regex:

```
(?!\s+Tax\s+)((\d+\.\d+)|\d+)$
```

replacer:

```
 #$&
```

result:

> Double Espresso 4 Mocha 55.42 Subtotal 72.45 Tax #5.98

Link: https://regexr.com/457ms

**Replace in C#**

```
var input = "Double Espresso 4 Mocha 55.42 Subtotal 72.45 Tax 5.98";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?!\sTax\s)((\d+\.\d+)|\d+)$", "#$1");
```

Comment: Adding # through replace worked but how it can replace a character like replace dot(.) with comma (,) to make result "5,98" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [`#$3$6`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28TAX%7CTax%29%28%5Ct%2B%7C%5Cs%2B%29%29%28.*%29%28%5Cd*%29%3F.%3F%28%5Cd*%29%3F%28%5Cd%2B%29&i=Double%20Espresso%204.75%20Subtotal%2072.45%20Tax%205.98&r=%23%243%246) for replacing with regex. If you don't know how to replace with regex in c# please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

Provided there is **always** a `.` in the Tax amount, you can do this to replace it into a comma and prefix the amount with a `$` using one regex like:

```
var subjectString = "Double Espresso 4 Mocha 55.42 Subtotal 72.45 Tax 5.98";
var result = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?!\sTax\s+)(\d+)(\.)?(\d+)?$", "$$$1,$3");
```

returns:

> ```
> Double Espresso 4.75 Subtotal 72.45 Tax $5,98
> ```

( you need to double-up the dollar signs for the prefix character because `$` has special meaning)

If you want a hash-symbol in front (`#`), there's no need for that kind of special care:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?!\sTax\s+)(\d+)(\.)?(\d+)?$", "#$1,$3");
```